# Want javascript validation for dropdown

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have dropdown which is filled from database

**HTML code is**:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd_j_name" CssClass="select2" runat="server" PlaceHolder="Select Journal" AutoPostBack="True" >  </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ImageButton ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validaterev();" ImageUrl="images/btn-submit1.jpg" />
```

`.cs code` is

```
dd_j_name.DataSource = rr_j_title;
dd_j_name.DataValueField = "EditorId1";
dd_j_name.DataTextField = "Title";
dd_j_name.DataBind();
dd_j_name.Items.Insert(0, "");
```

**My JavaScript code is**:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function validaterev() {
     if (document.getElementById("<%=dd_j_name.ClientID%>").value == "Select Journal" || document.getElementById("<%=dd_j_name.ClientID%>").value == "") 
        {
            alert("Required to Select Journal");
            document.getElementById("<%=dd_j_name.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

I am not able to show an alert of JavaScript as even i have not select any other things in dropdown list, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You should show your resulting HTML markup for the dropdown list. Also you should look at [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @lvaylo Slavov  actually  i am making registration page and i want this dropdown to be mandatory

Comment: Sorry mine mistake it is working...I used to click other button

Comment: A couple of things:

1. Your <asp:dropdown> definition has 'autopostback = true' - this means you are going to get a postback every time the user changes the selected dropdown. Is this what you want?
2. Since its ASP.NET you can do the validation using a custom validator where you check that a value has been selected (apart from the prompt item and blank), this is done server-side in VB.NET or C# code. You can then fail the validation if the required value isn't right and display a error message beside the dropdown.

Comment: lol... You used to click other button!!! lol...

Comment: now my focus to dropdown is not working

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the value of drop down, hence the value for first element is 0 not "Select Journal", you should try following code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function validaterev() {
     if (document.getElementById("<%=dd_j_name.ClientID%>").value == '0') 
        {
            alert("Required to Select Journal");
            document.getElementById("<%=dd_j_name.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)